Batch timer implementation
I have now realised that my timer script doesn't quite work.
When the timer ends, or when I input only 1 minute, it goes -1 days 23 hours...
Could someone please tell me how to do it similar to my code. There are other codes I have seen, but they have a fixed time and doesn't have the 2 seconds then 1 second feature that mine does.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:menu
cls
echo Instructions:
echo.
echo Select the amount of time you like.
echo Type "0" to not include that variable. e.g. Hours: 0
echo Would not include hours in the timer.
echo.
pause
goto input-days

:input-days
cls
set /p "days=How many days?: "
if not defined days goto input-days
goto input-hours

:input-hours
cls
set /p "hours=How many hours?: "
if not defined hours goto input-hours
goto input-minutes

:input-minutes
cls
set /p "minutes=How many minutes?: "
if not defined minutes goto input-minutes
goto input-seconds

:input-seconds
cls
set /p "seconds=How many seconds?: "
if not defined seconds goto input-seconds
goto check-seconds

:check-seconds
if %seconds% geq 60 (
    set /a minutes+=1
    set /a seconds-=1
)
goto check-minutes

:check-minutes
if %seconds% geq 60 (
    goto check-seconds
)

if %minutes% geq 60 (
    set /a hours+=1
    set /a minutes-=1
)
goto check-hours

:check-hours
if %minutes% geq 60 (
    goto check-minutes
)

if %hours% gtr 24 (
    set /a days+=1
    set /a hours-=24
)
goto noTextCursor-timer

:noTextCursor-timer
 For /f %%e in ('Echo Prompt $E^|cmd') Do set "\E=%%e"
 <nul Set /P "=%\E%[?25l"
 Set /A "delay=4", "Files=0","FC=1"

 For %%i in (5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5)Do (
  Set /A Files+=1
  Call :timer %%i "infile!Files!.txt"
 )

 For /L %%i in ()Do (
  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!time: =0!") do set /a "t2=(((1%%a*60)+1%%b)*60+1%%c)*100+1%%d-36610100, tDiff=t2-t1"
  if !tDiff! lss 0 set /a tDiff+=24*60*60*100
  if !tDiff! geq !delay! (
   Set /A "FC=FC %% Files + 1"
   <nul Set /P "=%\E%[1;0H"
   If !FC! GTR 10 (If !Offset! GTR 1 Set /A "Offset-=1")Else Set "offset=!FC!"
   (For /f "Delims=" %%G in (infile!FC!.txt)Do echo ^[[K%\E%[!offset!G%%G%\E%[E") > Con
   echo ^[[0J
   set /a t1=t2
  )
 )

:timer
<nul set /p "=%\E%[H"
if "%days%"=="1" (
    set "dayAmount=day"
) else (
    set "dayAmount=days"
)

if "%hours%"=="1" (
    set "hourAmount=hour"
) else (
    set "hourAmount=Hours"
)

if "%minutes%"=="1" (
    set "minuteAmount=minute"
) else (
    set "minuteAmount=minutes"
)

if "%seconds%"=="1" (
    set "secondAmount=second"
) else (
    set "secondAmount=seconds"
)

echo Timer: %days% %dayAmount%, %hours% %hourAmount%, %minutes% %minuteAmount%, ^& %seconds% %secondAmount% remaining.
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
set /a seconds-=1
if %seconds% leq 0 (
    set /a minutes-=1
    set seconds=59
)
if %minutes% leq 0 (
    set /a hours-=1
    set minutes=59
)
if %hours% leq 0 (
    set /a days-=1
    set hours=23
)
set check=seconds+minutes+hours+days
if %check% leq 0 (
    goto end
)
goto timer

:end
cls
echo The timer is finished!
pause

